# Injection code is there in spite of ngmin

Tags: jhipster

Why does jhipster have these duplicate dependency lists in the source files even though it uses ngmin to automatically add the injected dependencies as part of the build tasks so it's safe for minification?

For example, there is this code in services.js,

```
jhipsterApp.factory('Register', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('app/rest/register', {}, {
        });
    }]);
```

but since it uses ngmin, I would expect something like this, without the array and extra "$resource"

```
jhipsterApp.factory('Register', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('app/rest/register', {}, {
        });
    });
```

Is it just that the code was like this before ngmin was introduced and hasn't been simplified yet?  Maybe I don't understand it properly.

Comment: Hi, I'm the one who coded this: I had issues with minifications at that time, but this was nearly one year ago. If you can simplify it, please let me know! Of course, a Pull Request is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Cool. It sounds like I might not be totally clueless about this stuff afterall :-)  I'm still evaluating the options but will gladly help out if I end up settling on jhipster.  It looks like the meanjs.org code still has the duplication.  generator-angular and generator-angular-fullstack seem to have addressed it.  I can't say whether or not they have the problems you experienced.